# I'm just getting started with Solidity and ran into a deployment failed error when I try to migrate

Tags: solidity

this is the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Voting {

    address public owner;
    address public winnerAddress;
    uint public totalVote;
    bool votingStarted;

    struct Candidate{
        string name;
        uint age;
        bool registered;
        address candidateAddress;
        uint votes;
    }

    struct Voter{
        bool registered;
        bool voted;
    }

    event success(string msg);
    
    mapping(address=>uint) public candidates;
    Candidate[] public candidateList;
    mapping(address=>Voter) public voterList;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        totalVote = 0;
        votingStarted=false;
    }

    function registerCandidates(string memory _name, uint _age, address _candidateAddress) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can register Candidate!!");
        require(_candidateAddress != owner, "Owner can not participate!!");
        require(candidates[_candidateAddress] == 0, "Candidate already registered");
        Candidate memory candidate = Candidate({
            name: _name,
            age: _age,
            registered: true,
            votes: 0,
            candidateAddress: _candidateAddress
        });
        if(candidateList.length == 0){ //not pushing any candidate on location zero;
            candidateList.push();
        }
        candidates[_candidateAddress] = candidateList.length;
        candidateList.push(candidate);
        emit success("Candidate registered!!");
    }

    function whiteListAddress(address _voterAddress) public {
        require(_voterAddress != owner, "Owner can not vote!!");
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can whitelist the addresses!!");
        require(voterList[_voterAddress].registered == false, "Voter already registered!!");
        Voter memory voter = Voter({
            registered: true,
            voted: false
        });

        voterList[_voterAddress] = voter;
        emit success("Voter registered!!");
    }

    function startVoting() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can start voting!!");
        votingStarted = true;
        emit success("Voting Started!!");
    }

    function putVote(address _candidateAddress) public {
        require(votingStarted == true, "Voting not started yet or ended!!");
        require(msg.sender != owner, "Owner can not vote!!");
        require(voterList[msg.sender].registered == true, "Voter not registered!!");
        require(voterList[msg.sender].voted == false, "Already voted!!");
        require(candidateList[candidates[_candidateAddress]].registered == true, "Candidate not registered");

        candidateList[candidates[_candidateAddress]].votes++;
        voterList[msg.sender].voted =true;

        uint candidateVotes = candidateList[candidates[_candidateAddress]].votes;

        if(totalVote < candidateVotes){
            totalVote = candidateVotes;
            winnerAddress = _candidateAddress;
        }
        emit success("Voted !!");
        
    }

    function stopVoting() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can start voting!!");
        votingStarted = false;
        emit success("Voting stoped!!");
    }

    function getAllCandidate() public view returns(Candidate[] memory list){
        return candidateList;
    }

    function votingStatus() public view returns(bool){
        return votingStarted;
    }

    function getWinner() public view returns(Candidate memory candidate){
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can declare winner!!");
        return candidateList[candidates[winnerAddress]];
    }
}
```

and this is the deployment js code

```
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Voting);
};
```

the error im getting is

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Voting" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.
```

Truffle v5.10.0 (core: 5.10.0)
Node v18.16.1

Answer (score 0):

I must ask what version are you using for compilation. Because as I see you are using a floating pragma which is ^0.8.0. This might cause a problem when you are compiling with version 0.8.20.

This is because solidity 0.8.20 introduces the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode which is only supported on the ETH mainnet and not on any other chains. That's why other chains can't find the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode and throw this error.

Consider using 0.8.19 for other chains.

This should solve your problem.

If you want to learn more about PUSH0 opcode you can check this small article which explains it pretty well. https://www.zaryabs.com/push0-opcode/

EDIT - If you just installed Truffle and want to use older version of Solidity, you can simply specifying the compiler version in the truffle-config.js file:

```
  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.19", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version) 
     
    }
  }
```